# Extend or modify a Data View

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to extend the page's graph and modify the Datamember?

I have a new page that will add locations for an existing customer but would like to have those locations shown only on my page and not in the Locations tab of the Customer page.
Therefore, I will be extending the Location table to identify the records that are created from my new page and would have to modify the Customer Locations Datamember to the following

```
    public PXSelect<LocationExtAddress, Where<LocationExtAddress.locationBAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>,
And<LocationExtAddess.extendedField, IsNull>>>> Locations;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no delegate declared for `Locations` data view declared in the **BusinessAccountGraphBase** class (which is the base class for CustomerMaint):

```
public class BusinessAccountGraphBase<Base, Primary, WhereClause> : PXGraph<BusinessAccountGraphBase<Base, Primary, WhereClause>>
    where Base : BAccount, new()
    where Primary : class, IBqlTable, new()
    where WhereClause : class, IBqlWhere, new()
{
    ...
    public PXSelect<LocationExtAddress, Where<LocationExtAddress.locationBAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>>> Locations;
    ...
}
```

Therefore to modify `Locations` data view on the Customers screen, you should simply create an extension for the CustomerMaint BLC as follows:

```
public class CustomerMaintExt : PXGraphExtension<CustomerMaint>
{
    public PXSelect<LocationExtAddress, 
        Where<LocationExtAddress.locationBAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>,
            And<LocationExtAddess.extendedField, IsNull>>>> Locations;
}
```

For more information on this topic, see [Acumatica Customization Guide](https://docref.acumatica.com/wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=b1faf924-c742-4eb2-9a88-0fe299cf6137)