# Customizing a view in Acumatica

Tags: view, customization, acumatica

I want to customize the following view to filter `SOOrder` with `Open` Status. How can I do that?

```
public PXSelectJoin<SOOrder,LeftJoin<Users, On<Users.pKID, Equal<SOOrder.createdByID>>,
LeftJoin<SOOrderType, On<SOOrderType.orderType, Equal<SOOrder.orderType>>,
LeftJoin<PX.Objects.GL.Branch, On<PX.Objects.GL.Branch.branchID, Equal<SOOrder.branchID>>,
LeftJoin<Organization, On<Organization.organizationID, Equal<PX.Objects.GL.Branch.organizationID>, Or<Organization.organizationID, IsNull>>,
LeftJoin<PortalSetup, On2<Where<PortalSetup.restrictByOrganizationID, IsNull, Or<Organization.organizationID, Equal<PortalSetup.restrictByOrganizationID>>>,                 And<Where<PortalSetup.restrictByBranchID, IsNull, Or<PX.Objects.GL.Branch.branchID, Equal<PortalSetup.restrictByBranchID>>>>>>>>>>,
Where2<MatchWithBAccount<SOOrder.customerID, Current<AccessInfo.userID>>,                 And<PortalSetup.IsCurrentPortal>>,
OrderBy<Desc<SOOrder.orderNbr>>> Items;
```

I tried to customize it by adding `Where<SOOrder.Status, Equal<"N">>` But It gave me an Error.

Answer (score 0):

I replied in the Acumatica community.
Here is a copy of the reply:

You have a couple of options to go about this:

1 - You could redefine the Data view in your Graph Extension.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962911/extend-or-modify-a-data-view) is more info on how to do that:

2 - You could add additional filtering elements in the Graph Extension’s Initialize() method.

It would look something like:

```
public override void Initialize()
{

    this.Base.Items.WhereNew<Where<SOOrder.status, Equal<SOOrderStatus.open>>>();

}
```

Comment: UPDATE: Per feedback received in the Acumatica community, WhereNew<> will fully replace the original Where clause.
It can be used, but you have to make sure to include the original clauses along with the new one